# Embed Typeform into React using Custom Button Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, tailwind-css, typeform

I'm trying to embed a Typeform contact form in my Gatsby React website. All the examples I've seen use the basic html `button` as an example, however that falls away from my website's theme. This is an example of the code I'm using to embed the typeform:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed';

class ContactInfo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const popup1 = typeformEmbed.makePopup('URL', {
      mode: 'drawer_right',
      autoclose: 3000,
      hideHeaders: true,
      onSubmit: function () {
        console.log('Typeform successfully submitted');
      }
    });

    document.getElementById('bt-popup').addEventListener('click', function () {
      popup1.open();
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="bt-popup" class="my-button">
          Popup
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactInfo;
```

However, I have my own button component created here which I would like to use instead of the one in the example. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import * as Styled from './styles';

const Button = ({ primary, block, children }) => (
  <Styled.Button primary={primary} block={block} whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }} whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}>
    {children}
  </Styled.Button>
);

Button.propTypes = {
  primary: PropTypes.bool,
  block: PropTypes.bool,
  children: PropTypes.any.isRequired
};

export default Button;
```

How do I replace the `<button>` with my own component `<Button>` so that it is in keeping with the site theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed';
import Button from 'path/to/button/component'

class ContactInfo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const popup1 = typeformEmbed.makePopup('URL', {
      mode: 'drawer_right',
      autoclose: 3000,
      hideHeaders: true,
      onSubmit: function () {
        console.log('Typeform successfully submitted');
      }
    });

    document.getElementById('bt-popup').addEventListener('click', function () {
      popup1.open();
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button id="bt-popup" class="my-button">
          Popup
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactInfo;
```

*Note: you may need to use `createPopop` (`^1.01`) instead of `makePopup` depending on your Typeform version.*

Keep in mind that accessing directly to the DOM (as you do use `document.getElementById`) is not the best approach in terms of best practices because it has a huge performance impact (such jQuery for example). Indeed, this is why you are using React, which creates a virtual DOM. You can replicate the same behavior using [`useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

Comment: Hi Ferran, actually when I tried this- the button component comes out but once you click on it, the typeform doesn't popup...

Comment: So I get: 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

When I use `Button` instead of `button`

Comment: It's alright! I think I have solved it. Thanks very much Ferran!

Comment: FYI : `makePopup` is replaced by `createPopup` in the newer version of `@typeform/embed` @1.01.